# How to RegEx - match to pattern but with exclusion?

Tags: regex

I have а sequence like:

```
0-2014
1-2014
2-2014
...
11-2014
12-2014
0-2015
0-2016
0-2017
...
```

I need match any of them but with exclusion `0-2014`

Now I have only common way without exclusion:

```
(([0-9]{1,2})-20([0-9]{2}))
```

So the question: is it possible to exclude `0-2014` from matching? And How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [negative look ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) :

```
((?!0-2014)([0-9]{1,2})-20([0-9]{2}))
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/oQ1mF3/1)

Also if you don't need inner groups you can use non capture-grouping for them :

```
((?!0-2014)(?:[0-9]{1,2})-20(?:[0-9]{2}))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```
(?!0-2014)(([0-9]{1,2})-20([0-9]{2}))
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/yS3lY3/1)

Comment: Thank you very much! Sorry but @Kasra was a second faster.